# Using pytest.raises to inspect custom exception attributes

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, pytest

```
class CustomException(ValueError):
  def __init__(self, foo, bar):
    self.foo = foo
    self.bar = bar
```

I have a class with an exception like the above. `foo` and `bar` are used by the function raising the error to supply some extra information about the exception to the calling class.

I'm trying to test this behavior like this:

```
with pytest.raises(CustomException) as ce:
  func_that_raises(broken_args)
assert ce.foo == 'blah'
assert not ce.bar  # if `bar` is expected to be a boolean
```

However, `ce` is an instance of `ExceptionInfo` that py.test gives me, and *not* an instance of `CustomException`. Is there any way to retain and inspect the original exception that was raised?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The actual exception object is available as `ce.value`, so your asserts need to be written as:

```
assert ce.value.foo == 'blah'
assert not ce.value.bar
```